# I can't install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: apt, sudo

When I try to install ubuntu-restricted-extras, using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`,  I get the following error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 0):

Juste wait a few seconds and try again.
It's probably because a background process is currently checking for updates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `apt-get` was stopped prematurely while it was still busy doing something as a result, `apt` is still in a locked state.Do the following:

Restart your machine (`sudo reboot`) and try to install again.

If at this point you still cant install the, then do the following:

- Delete the lock file:

  `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`
- Delete the lock file in the cache directory:

  `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`
- Install ubuntu-restricted-extras:

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`